# Sound through headphones is crackling/popping

Tags: sound, alsa

The sound through my speakers is fine, however it cracks/popples when played through my headphones. While looking for a solution, I found [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/442463/comments/4). I tested this by unplugging my headphones, plugging them in again, and then quickly playing sound through them. The sound sounds file for ten seconds, then it starts crackling and popping again. However, there is no

```
options snd-hda-intel power_save=10 power_save_controller=N
```

in my alsa-base.conf file. Is there an alternate parameter that I can change?

Comment: Just checking, you use an alternate port on your sound card for headphones?

Comment: @jeremija: I am using a USB port with an M-Audio FastTrack MKII for sound. It has worked fine in previous installations (running an older version of Ubuntu).

Comment: It seems really weird because that's actually the same stereo channel, plugging the headphones in just makes the soundcard redirect the main output to headphones, right?

Comment: @jeremija: Plugging the FastTrack adds two more output channels called 'Digital Output (S/PDIF)' and 'Analog Output'. Both output sounds through the headphones.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10907007&postcount=10):

> Try resetting your pulse configuration.
>
> Using a Terminal="Applications->Accessories->Terminal"
>
> ```
> rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.asound* ~/.pulse-cookie 
> sudo rm /etc/asound.conf
> ```
>
> Reboot and ignore any 'No such file or directory' errors

Comment: I tried that previously to no avail. I just tried it again and nothing changed.