# USB Headphone audio popping on Ubuntu 20.04.2LTS

Tags: sound, usb, alsa, headphones

I know there are a lot of posts with near subjects
I tried all this solutions without success

[Sound Cracking and Popping Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177762/sound-cracking-and-popping-ubuntu-19-04)

[Annoying click/popping sound on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230833/annoying-click-popping-sound-on-ubuntu-20-04)

[Sound through headphones is crackling/popping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176036/sound-through-headphones-is-crackling-popping)

My installation is fresh and I tested with two different USB headphones. The popping happen in both but, if I plug a simple P2 (like of smartphones) it works fine.
Anyone have some idea?

uname -r

```
5.8.0-59-generic
```

inxi -A

```
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 5 Series/3400 Series High Definition Audio 
  driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: Logitech Headset H390 type: USB 
  driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-59-generic
```

Comment: Hi. Did you solve this in some way? I mean, upgrading to 20.04 or so

Answer (score 1):

For me

changes in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
from

```
;default-sample-rate=44100
```

to

```
default-sample-rate=48000
```

Fixed the issue